# How to create view/single record based on multiple tables/records

Tags: sql, view

I need help creating a view in SQL 2008 that would create a single record that is comprised of data from two tables with one of tables containg multiple records.

```
Table 1 contains field A, B
Table 2 contains field A,B,1
                       A,B,2
                       A,B,3
                       A,B,4
                       A,B,5
```

I am looking for a result view that is

```
A,B,1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: Is it just me or is this data not normalized?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to look into using `STUFF` and `FOR XML`:

```
SELECT t.col1, t.col2, 
  STUFF((
    select ',' + cast(t2.id as varchar) 
    from yourothertable t2 
    where t.col1 = t2.col1 and t.col2 = t2.col2
    for xml path('')
        ), 1, 1, '') 
from yourtable t
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8d3e2/1)

If you want to combine the 3 columns, easy enough to do using the `'+'` operator.

```
SELECT t.col1 + ',' + t.col2 + 
  (
    select ',' + cast(t2.id as varchar) 
    from yourothertable t2 
    where t.col1 = t2.col1 and t.col2 = t2.col2
    for xml path('')
        )
from yourtable t;
```